# Hadoop error with map-reduce job with security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException (no such file or directory)

Tags: python, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am running a simple streaming map-reduce job and can't seem to get by this error.

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.2.1.jar -input textDataFiles/* -output counts -file /home/hduser/first/mapper.py -mapper mapper.py -file /home/hduser/first/reducer.py -reducer reducer.py
```

And the result is:

```
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

packageJobJar: [/home/hduser/first/mapper.py, /home/hduser/first/reducer.py] [] /tmp/streamjob1639740860313757975.jar tmpDir=null
14/01/19 00:04:57 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
14/01/19 00:04:57 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hduser cause:ENOENT: No such file or directory
14/01/19 00:04:57 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Error Launching job : No such file or directory
Streaming Command Failed!
```

There is nothing particular about my mapper and reducer - it is a simple word counting script. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your command line appears correct since used the -file to the full path and then w/o the path for invoking. I will be interested in answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem recently on my school's hadoop cluster.
The issue was in privileges for `/tmp/hadoop-USERNAME` directory, mounted on a regular filesystem. `USERNAME` stands for my username on linux machine that I connect to.
Deleting that directory solved the problem.